# CSS Styles specific to Admin Sidebar not loading

Tags: admin, tinymce, editor, admin-css

I have several sites where I have loaded a custom stylesheet for the Admin. They work fine in both the TinyMCE editor and the sidebars.

I have one site where the custom stylesheet targets the TinyMCE styles properly, but does not seem to target anything in the sidebar. The only variable is that I'm using JetPack 'Free' on this one site, which seems to somehow override styling in the sidebars.

However, perhaps I am heading down the wrong alley because I have tried deactivating JetPack (not uninstalling) and it does not seem to address the issue.

Is JetPack a likely culprit? Is there a way to prevent it from overriding my custom CSS? Or is there some other obvious issue I'm missing here?

Again: my custom stylesheet works -fine- within the DIV for TinyMCE, it is only the sidebars which are being ignored.

Comment: What do you mean by “sidebars”? And what specific changes are being overwritten?

Comment: As for this - "Is JetPack a likely culprit?" - you could just try deactivating the plugin, and see if the same issue persists. You could also try clearing your caches and see if it helps.

Comment: I use the 2-column format in the Post Editor. The post editor is in the left column. The sidebar are in the right column. I call that the 'sidebars'. Their IDs are postbox-container-1 and postbox-container-2. Column 1 responds to CSS. Column 2 (the sidebars) are not targeted by my custom CSS file.

Comment: I tried de-activating JetPack and it does not solve the problem. I understand that it is an extreme longshot, but I am grasping at straws. I have a dozen web sites that all load that custom CSS properly and the only site where it does not is the one we were trying JetPack with.

Comment: For some reason, this site loads a file like common.css from c0.wp.com and I have no idea why.